# Error while creating array of objects in NS-3 (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, ns-3

In an NS-3 `.cc` file I am trying to create an array of instantiations of the `UdpEchoClientHelper`class, just by doing:

```
UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient[NO_OF_NODES];
```

and when I am trying to build I am getting the error message:

```
../scratch/test.cc:55:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘ns3::UdpEchoClientHelper::UdpEchoClientHelper()’
```

Am I doing something wrong at the array declaration?

Comment: You can try `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<UdpEchoClientHelper>>` and set the smart pointers later. I don't know what UdpEchoClientHelper is specifically, so there may be a more appropriate solution for that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no matching constructor for

```
UdpEchoClientHelper::UdpEchoClientHelper()
```

These are the available constructors:

```
   /**
   * Create UdpEchoClientHelper which will make life easier for people trying
   * to set up simulations with echos.
   *
   * \param ip The IP address of the remote udp echo server
   * \param port The port number of the remote udp echo server
   */
  UdpEchoClientHelper (Address ip, uint16_t port);
  /**
   * Create UdpEchoClientHelper which will make life easier for people trying
   * to set up simulations with echos.
   *
   * \param ip The IPv4 address of the remote udp echo server
   * \param port The port number of the remote udp echo server
   */
  UdpEchoClientHelper (Ipv4Address ip, uint16_t port);
  /**
   * Create UdpEchoClientHelper which will make life easier for people trying
   * to set up simulations with echos.
   *
   * \param ip The IPv6 address of the remote udp echo server
   * \param port The port number of the remote udp echo server
   */
  UdpEchoClientHelper (Ipv6Address ip, uint16_t port);
```

You should take a look to the tutorials first.